# Want to save Bytes data that comes from a sensor as Audio file then play in android

Tags: c#, jquery, css, performance

I have a sensor that captures the heart's sounds and my problem is that I receive my data as bytes then convert to floats. I just want to collect the data and put it in an Audio file then play from the file manger. i have tried lots of ways but been confused for non of the attempts i have made worked. guys I really need your help.Ps.. i have tried MediaPlayer and did not work. i will be so thankful if someone could solve this perplexing problem. for more clarification, my problem is that i get data that contains a signal of the heart's sound, when it bumps and so on. i receive the data using bluetooth and when done, i covert the data into numbers,float,.I'm tryna save this data in an audio file while receiving the data then play it when I click on stop button. basically, it's kinda like recording the data as an audio then play. MediaRecorder API in android allows you to do so but through the phone's mic and i do not want the mic. My data is ready but how to create an audio file and push the data into it then play it

```js
int BufferElements2Rec = 1024; // want to play 2048 (2K) since 2 bytes we use only 1024
    int BytesPerElement = 2; // 2 bytes in 16bit format

    private void startRecording() {

        recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
                RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement);


        recorder.startRecording();
        isRecording = true;
        recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                writeAudioDataToFile();
            }
        }, "AudioRecorder Thread");
        recordingThread.start();
    }

    //convert short to byte
    private byte[] short2byte(short[] sData) {
        int shortArrsize = sData.length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[shortArrsize * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < shortArrsize; i++) {
            bytes[i * 2] = (byte) (sData[i] & 0x00FF);
            bytes[(i * 2) + 1] = (byte) (sData[i] >> 8);
            sData[i] = 0;
        }
        return bytes;

    }

    private void writeAudioDataToFile() {
        // Write the output audio in byte

        String filePath =  getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
        filePath+="/audiorecordtest.3gp";
        int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
                RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);
        byte sData[] = new byte[bufferSize];

        FileOutputStream os = null;
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (isRecording) {
            // gets the voice output from microphone to byte format

            recorder.read(sData, 0, BufferElements2Rec);
            System.out.println("Short wirting to file" + sData.toString());
            try {
                // // writes the data to file from buffer
                // // stores the voice buffer
                byte bData[] = audioBuffer;
                os.write(bData, 0, BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        // stops the recording activity
        if (null != recorder) {
            isRecording = false;
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();
            recorder = null;
            recordingThread = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: my problem is that i get data that contains a signal of the heart's sound, when it bumps and so on. i receive the data using bluetooth and when done, i covert the data into numbers,float,.I'm tryna save this data in an audio file while receiving the data then play it when I click on stop button. basically, it's kinda like recording the data as an audio then play. MediaRecorder API in android allows you to do so but through the phone's mic and i do not want the mic. My data is ready but how to create an audio file and push the data into it then play it.